# Delaying One RSS Feed in WordPress but Not the Others?

Tags: rss, feed

Is there anyway to create a special feed in WordPress that is on a delay that I can distribute to some of our content partners? I found some [tutorials on how to delay your feed](http://wpengineer.com/publish-the-feed-later/) but it uses the conditional statement `is_feed` and I don't want to apply this to all feeds, just one particular feed. Any advice?

**Edit:**  To clarify, I want to provide one full feed that publishes in real time (the native WP feed) and another full feed that displays the same content but is on a delay so it doesn't update until after the time period that I specify.

Comment: I answered your question. Please can you give more details or an example about the particular type of feed you want to delay? With more details, I can provide a more specific answer.

Comment: *@matt*: Yes, agreed with @sorich87; please provide a lot of detail with your questions.  Please provide a lot of detail including example use-cases and why you need something  instead of short and abstract questions. It will help everyone, now and in the future, and get you quicker and better answers if you give us better questions.

Comment: So you want something in the style of `http://www.example.com/feed` and `http://www.example.com/feed/delayed`?

Comment: @Jan, yes, that sounds good.

Comment: You can also go here and create a delayed RSS feed very painlessly: http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=plwADZXk3RGOD5GUPxJ3AQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tutorial explains how to create a custom feed: http://yoast.com/custom-rss-feeds-wordpress/.
Put the add_filter (from the wpengineer tutorial) before the query_post, and a remove_filter('posts_where', 'publish_later_on_feed'); after it.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I just need a little more clarification: When you say "Put the add_filter (from the wpengineer tutorial) before the query_post," do you mean just the "add_filter" line or the whole function from wpengineer beginning with `function publish_later_on_feed($where) {`?  Also, 'and a remove_filter('posts_where', 'publish_later_on_feed'); after it."  Do you mean after to insert it directly after this line: `$posts = query_posts('showposts='.$numposts);` ?

Comment: Yes, the whole function before `$posts = query_posts('showposts='.$numposts);` and `remove_filter('posts_where', 'publish_later_on_feed');` after `$posts = query_posts('showposts='.$numposts);`.